# Comparing four columns at once while their out of order and different lengths

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am utilizing google sheets to compare check numbers and amounts I want to vet against any incoming check numbers that are not correct on my side while also making sure the check numbers that do match have matching amounts. I think my code is almost working but I am unsure what I am missing. It correctly detects incorrect check numbers (Column C) but it does not detect incorrect check amounts(Column D). I need to be able to write to the console with the following logic:

1. When Column C value is not found in column C on a separate tab/sheet
2. When column C and D are not found in Column C and D on a separate sheet
3. When column C matches on both sheets but the amounts in column D is different.

Expected result from the console log would be:
Row C54 has a inconsistent check number
or
Row C42 has an inconsistent check amount

Any insight on what I am missing to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
          function CHK_BothChecks_V3() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const s1 = ss.getSheetByName("OpenCheckDataBase");
  const s2 = ss.getSheetByName("IncomingChecks");

    var range1 = s1.getRange("C1:D").getValues();
    var range2 = s2.getRange("C1:D").getValues();
    var correctChecks = 0;
    var invalidChecks = 0;
    var invalidAmounts = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < range1.length;i++) {
        if(range1[i][0] == range2[i][0]) {
          correctChecks++;
        }
               else if(range1[i][0] !== range2[i][0]) {
          var index = s1.getRange(i+1, 2).getRow();
          invalidChecks++; 
          console.log(index); /** This is the row locations of where inconsistant check numbers will show up */
        }

    
    }
        console.log("Total number of valid check numbers is " + correctChecks);
        console.log("Total number of invalid check numbers is " + invalidChecks);
        console.log("Total number of invalid amounts is " + invalidAmounts);

 }
```

Comment: With `range1[i][0]` and `range2[i][0]`, you are only every accessing the first column in the requested range (denoted by `0`), which is column C. Since we never see `range1[i][1]` or `range2[i][1]` in your code, we can say that your code never interacts at all with column D throughout the whole process, so you are missing all the logic around that.

Comment: I did not know that is how it worked honestly and always assumed the [i][0] was iterating through the entire column starting at the very first row or portion of the range. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function CHK_BothChecks_V3() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("OpenCheckDataBase");
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("IncomingChecks");
  var rg1 = sh1.getRange("C1:D" + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var rg2 = sh2.getRange("C1:D" + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var correctChecks = 0;
  var invalidChecks = 0;
  var invalidAmounts = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < rg1.length; i++) {
    if (rg1[i][0] == rg2[i][0]) {
      correctChecks++;
    } else if (rg1[i][0] !== rg2[i][0]) {
      var index = sh1.getRange(i + 1, 2).getRow();
      invalidChecks++;
      console.log(index); 
    }
  }
  console.log("Total number of valid check numbers is " + correctChecks);
  console.log("Total number of invalid check numbers is " + invalidChecks);
  console.log("Total number of invalid amounts is " + invalidAmounts);
}
```

If this doesn't help then please post some of your data and explain what you are  looking for.  Please post data using tables so that it can be copied and pasted

Comment: This worked amazing! I forgot the value of using getLastRow for iterating through the range. Thank you!!

Comment: If I could add one more request. If one of the ranges is significantly larger than the other one (sh1 in this case has 5000 rows) and sh2 being only 40 rows. How can I prevent it from running out of room to iterate like with TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')? Since we are trying to compare sh2's data and  find out if they are match able in sh1 if that makes sense?

Comment: Ask it as another question